# PostgreSQL error when trying to create an extension on windows

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I already download `postgis-2.1.5-5` from http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/pg94/buildbot

But, when I run `CREATE EXTENSION sfcgal;` I get this error:

> ERROR: could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/share/extension/sfcgal.control": No such file or directory SQL state: 58P01

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the documentation, you should first [install PostGIS](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/postgis_installation.html#install_short_version), then [execute postgis/sfcgal.sql](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/reference.html#reference_sfcgal) to make available all sfcgal functions in postgresql.

Read the `README.txt` file at the root directory of the zip you've downloaded, it describes everything that should be done in order to be able to `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` under windows.

Comment: So, how can I use "srcgal" ?

Comment: See documentation for use of sfcgal function in postgresql http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/reference.html#reference_sfcgal

Comment: Tnx @ Jérôme Radix.  I saw this page, and I download the ".zip" one, then, I copy all files on postgresql's directory, but it get the error,yet:

ERROR: could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/postgis-2.2.dll": The specified procedure could not be found.
SQL state: XX000

Comment: read README.txt, it tells you all steps needed to be able to `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` and then be able to execute the `sfcgal.sql`

Comment: Dear @ Jérôme Radix, Tnx for your useful help. The point was I should copy and REPLACE all files.